# With excel formula A1/$A$1, change $A$1 ref when another cell value changes

Tags: excel

In the following (very simplified) example, I'd like to calculate `B1/$B$1` for row 1, and repeat for each row (i.e. `B2/$B$1`, `B3/$B$2` etc). When the value of column A changes, I need it to change (in the example below) to `B4/$B$4` on row 4 and then `B6/$B$6` in row 6 (and so on).

```
    A    B 
-----------
1|  2    2  
2|  2    5  
3|  2    8  
4|  3    2  
5|  3    4  
6|  4   15  
7|  4    3  
8|  4    7
```

Hope this makes sense. Suggestions for any formulas/macros very much appreciated.

Comment: Your example is very confusing. Can you mock-up what you want to see in Excel and post a screenshot into your question?

Answer (score 2):

You might use a "helper" column C in which the denominator can be calculated for each row depending on a change of value in column A. Then you can use relative links to calculate the result in Column D.

Example:

```
A  |  B  |          C          |    D
2  |  2  |  =B1                |  =B1/C1
2  |  5  |  =IF(A2<>A1,B2,C1)  |  =B2/C2
2  |  8  |  =IF(A3<>A2,B3,C2)  |  =B3/C3
3  |  5  |  =IF(A4<>A3,B4,C3)  |  =B4/C4
3  |  4  |  =IF(A5<>A4,B5,C4)  |  =B5/C5
4  |  9  |  =IF(A6<>A5,B6,C5)  |  =B6/C6
4  |  3  |  =IF(A7<>A6,B7,C6)  |  =B7/C7
4  |  7  |  =IF(A8<>A7,B8,C7)  |  =B8/C8
```

Please note that you will need to set an init value for row 1 (cell C1). From row 2 on you can simply copy and paste formulas from C2:D2.

Comment: Thanks for your answers - on looking at my example more closely, I can see the reason it's confusing is because I'm confused! Many apologies; will look at what I'm trying to achieve more closely and post back when I'm clearer.

Comment: +1 your helper column gives reflects the value of A that the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't very clear what you're trying to do.  However, if you are using column A to specify the cell that the formula in B is using, you should utilize the OFFSET function.

Example: set cell A5 to 5.  In cell C5 use `=B5 / OFFSET($B$1,A5-1,0)`

This is the same as `=B5/B5`.  But if you change cell A5 to 7, then it's the same as `=B5/B7`.